# How to hide specific services from grpc reflection?

Tags: reflection, grpc, grpc-java

Im currently running a gRPC server with a reflection service as well to expose my services.

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(9092)
            .addService(ProtoReflectionService.newInstance())
            .addService(new StructServiceImpl())
            .addService(new ChatServiceImpl()).build();
    server.start();
```

Here, both my `StructService` and `ChatService` are exposed via reflection. I need to know whether there is a way to reflect only the `ChatService` and do not expose the `StructService` to the external parties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment `ProtoReflectionService` does not support this functionality. While not ideal, one thing you could do is running `StructServiceImpl` in a separate server:

```java
Server structSerivceServer = ServerBuilder.forPort(9093)
    .addService(ProtoReflectionService.newInstance())
    .addService(new StructServiceImpl())
    .build();
structSerivceServer.start();

Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(9092)
    .addService(new ChatServiceImpl())
    .build();
server.start();
```

Feel free to file a [feature request](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=feature_report.md) at grpc-java GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for info. I think it is a good feature to have. Will create a request.